# Principal Component Rotation matrix with different dimension

Tags: r, pca

I am not able to understand why is this happening. I have a data matrix which is (64x6830). When I do the following

```
pr.out=prcomp(data,scale=TRUE)
dim(pr.out$rotation)
# [1] 6830   64
```

I am not able to understand why the rotation matrix is not 6830x6830. When I take a subset of data like this:

```
data1=data[1:nrow(data),1:10]
pr.data=prcomp(data1,scale=TRUE)
dim(pr.data$rotation)
# [1] 10 10
```

So for smaller size from the same data is giving correct, but I am clueless why it is giving a different rotation matrix when done on the whole dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The function `prcomp` is based on the function `svd`:

```
svd(x, nu = min(n, p), nv = min(n, p), LINPACK = FALSE)
```

From `edit(stats:::prcomp.default)`, we see:

```
s <- svd(x, nu = 0)
```

This means that the left singular vectors are not computed. Thus, in the case of `prcomp`, `svd` only returns `"a vector containing the singular values of x, of length min(n, p)"` and `"a matrix whose columns contain the right singular vectors of x [...]. Dimension c(p, nv)"`

If we go back to the call of `svd`, `nv` is defined as `nv = min(n, p)` (minimum between `n` and `p`), where `n = row(x)` and `p = ncol(x)`.

1. In the case of "data", `n = 64` and `p = 6830`. Then `nv = 64` and `pr.out$rotation` is a 6830x64 (p x nv) matrix
2. In the case of "data1", `n = 10` and `p = 10`. Then `nv = 10` and and `pr.out$rotation` is a 10x10 (p x nv) matrix

Comment: I think it is giving us the reduced cols or basically the rank of the matrix. Here nv would be the rank or no. of independent cols. Rest it is discarding

Comment: If you don't specifiy a tolerance `tol` in `prcomp`, there is no rank calculated. The size of `rotation` is given by the `svd` algorithm.